# Why does content not show when going from flex: column to flex: row?

Tags: css, flexbox

In the snippet below, you'll see that in screen sizes under 768px, I can see the video and content beneath it. When I go to anything above 768px, the video disappears.

**Why does the video disappear when going from `flex-direction: column;` to `flex-direction: row;`?**

**[Codepen here](https://codepen.io/r3hab/pen/LYLWrEV) if you'd prefer...**

```css
/* Duru Sans */
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Duru+Sans&display=swap");
/*resets*/
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  font-family: "Duru Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000a70;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
  padding-right: 24px;
  padding-left: 24px;
  width: 100%;
}

.people-love-cats h2 {
  font-size: 2.25rem;
  line-height: 2.75rem;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.video-slider {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .video-slider {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}
.video-slider__video {
  /* embed video */
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.video-slider__video iframe,
.video-slider__video object,
.video-slider__video embed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.video-slider__content {
  padding: 2rem;
  background: #f2f5f9;
}
.video-slider__content h6.kicker.kicker--light {
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  line-height: 0.75rem;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.video-slider__content h4 {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.75rem;
  line-height: 2.25rem;
  font-weight: 900;
}
.video-slider__content p {
  margin-top: 1.25rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}
.video-slider__content .txt-link {
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.txt-link {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.txt-link a {
  color: #005fec;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  position: relative;
}
.txt-link a:hover::after {
  visibility: visible;
  width: 100%;
}
.txt-link a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -5px;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #005fec;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.txt-link img {
  height: 0.75rem;
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="people-love-cats">
    <h2>People love Cats.</h2>
    <div class="video-slider">
      <div class="video-slider__video">
        <iframe src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/2acZIOSV9LY' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="video-slider__content">
        <h6 class="kicker kicker--light">
          Customer Story
        </h6>
        <h4>Company Name</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae, maiores.</p>
        <span class="txt-link arrow-link">
          <a href="#">Read more</a>
          <img alt="arrow right icon" class="learn-more-arrow" src="https://nextivaweb.imgix.net/icons/Arrow-Right-Hover-Animation.svg" loading="lazy">
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: because no width. On a column direction you have the stretch alignment that gives you full width

Answer (score 0):

**Hi**,

Because No Width you add `max-width:100%` yeah .

But in your case mean `width: 100%` .

Just add specified width in the media query.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .video-slider {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .video-slider__content {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .video-slider__video {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

See After Edit it working

```css
/* Duru Sans */
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Duru+Sans&display=swap");
/*resets*/
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  font-family: "Duru Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000a70;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
  padding-right: 24px;
  padding-left: 24px;
  width: 100%;
}

.people-love-cats h2 {
  font-size: 2.25rem;
  line-height: 2.75rem;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.video-slider {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .video-slider {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .video-slider__content {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .video-slider__video {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
.video-slider__video {
  /* embed video */
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.video-slider__video iframe,
.video-slider__video object,
.video-slider__video embed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.video-slider__content {
  padding: 2rem;
  background: #f2f5f9;
}
.video-slider__content h6.kicker.kicker--light {
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  line-height: 0.75rem;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.video-slider__content h4 {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.75rem;
  line-height: 2.25rem;
  font-weight: 900;
}
.video-slider__content p {
  margin-top: 1.25rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}
.video-slider__content .txt-link {
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.txt-link {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.txt-link a {
  color: #005fec;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  position: relative;
}
.txt-link a:hover::after {
  visibility: visible;
  width: 100%;
}
.txt-link a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -5px;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #005fec;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.txt-link img {
  height: 0.75rem;
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <div class="people-love-cats">
        <h2>People love Cats.</h2>
        <div class="video-slider">
          <div class="video-slider__video">
            <iframe
              src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2acZIOSV9LY"
              frameborder="0"
              allowfullscreen
            ></iframe>
          </div>
          <div class="video-slider__content">
            <h6 class="kicker kicker--light">Customer Story</h6>
            <h4>Company Name</h4>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae,
              maiores.
            </p>
            <span class="txt-link arrow-link">
              <a href="#">Read more</a>
              <img
                alt="arrow right icon"
                class="learn-more-arrow"
                src="https://nextivaweb.imgix.net/icons/Arrow-Right-Hover-Animation.svg"
                loading="lazy"
              />
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```